# VB.net function giving ORA-00911 invalid character error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, data-access-layer, ora-00911

```
 Public Shared Function GetData(ByVal id As Integer) As List(Of SomeClass)
            Dim command As New OracleCommand       
            Dim conn As New OracleConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ToString)
            Dim param As New OracleParameter
            param.ParameterName = "idnumber"
            param.Value = id
            param.DbType = DbType.Int32
            command.Parameters.Add(param) 

            command.Connection = conn
            command.CommandText = "select VAL1, VAL2, Year from local.proc where id = :idnumber and Year = to_number(to_char(sysdate,’YYYY’))"

            Dim reader As OracleDataReader
            Dim someList As New List(Of SomeClass)

            connection.Open()
            reader = command.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read
                Dim someClass As New SomeClass
                someClass.VAL1 = reader("VAL1")
                someClass.VAL2 = reader("VAL2")
                someClass.Year = reader("YEAR")
                someList.Add(someClass)
            End While
            connection.Close()
            Return someList
        End Function
```

This function is giving an ORA-00911 invalid character error. I have other methods of the same style and these are functioning correctly. Any advise on where I am going wrong here please? Thanks

Comment: You are missing a parameter `:idnumber` - do you have it in your actual code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is with the wrong quotes in the SQL statement for the year i.e. : `’YYYY’`

Change it to `'YYYY'`

Replace the line:

```
command.CommandText = "select VAL1, VAL2, Year from local.proc where id = :idnumber and Year = to_number(to_char(sysdate,’YYYY’))"
```

with

```
command.CommandText = "select VAL1, VAL2, Year from local.proc where id = :idnumber and Year = to_number(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY'))"
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using formatted apostrophes.

```
to_char(sysdate,’YYYY’
```

try change it to

```
to_char(sysdate,'YYYY'
```